# excute php code after every Wordpress's new post

Tags: php, wordpress, post, execute

I made a wordpress site which is fully responsive, then I developed an iOS App that uses xmlParser to fetch news feeds from my wordpress
I even included push notifications to my app, now what I'm looking for is :?
where to place a php code that will be excuted every time I make a new post so I can send push notifications to my app users 
I look for the "wordpress" files, but I couldn't figure out the right place that will grab the post title, link and contents so I can send them

please help!
thanx

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post

Answer (score 0):

Add this in functions.php :

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'your_function' );

function your_function( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
    // Magic.
    // (Check your post type because this will be fired on page creation too.)
}
```

This will cause `your_function()` to be called every time you insert a new post.

Codex : https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post